# setTimeout reset for long durations

Tags: javascript, jquery, timer, settimeout, reset

I have a setTimeout function that starts 25-minutes in and resets/restarts the next 25-minutes. My test script clearly works when I change it from 1500000ms to something shorter like 1000ms; however it does not when I (tediously) test it every 25-minutes (1500000ms). Any suggestions?

```js
//    1000ms = 1s
//    60000ms = 60s         // 1 min
//    1500000 = 1500s       // 25 mins

var timer = null;
timer = setTimeout(sessionFunction, 1500000);

function sessionFunction() {
    alert('test');
    clearTimeout(timer);  
    timer = setTimeout(sessionFunction, 1500000);
}
```

```
//    1000ms = 1s
//    60000ms = 60s         // 1 min
//    1500000 = 1500s       // 25 mins

var timer = null;
timer = setTimeout(sessionFunction, 1500000);

function sessionFunction() {
    alert('test');
    clearTimeout(timer);      
    timer = setTimeout(sessionFunction, 1500000);
}
```

Comment: As a side note, you could use `setInterval` instead of manually clearing and reseting the timer

Comment: Do you hide the browser tab when it is running?

Comment: Yes, in some cases. This will be used as a session timeout warning dialog so the user may have their tab/window running in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest changing the script so that the timer fires every minute and keeps a counter of each time it fires.  Once the counter hits 25 then you know 25 minutes have passed.  The code won't be quite as simple, but it does avoid the issue you have encountered where the timer is not firing.

Comment: A very nice workaround! Thank you! Looks like this is the only option I have so far so I'll accept this answer; however, I'd love to see other alternatives from others.